# Meaning of っちろい

Tags: meaning, conjugations, suffixes

I was reading through the Lore section of a newly released item in Fate/Grand Order and came across a strange suffix/conjugation to a word.

> 胸を張って、**弱っちろい**世界のために戦え。

The translation given for the word was "feeble", which makes sense due to the usage of 弱.

I searched around a bit and couldn't find a particular meaning, however I did find a similar word in 生っちろい (meaning: pale or pasty), in which the ちろい part appears to actually be 白い.

My major questions are:

- What is the significance of っちろい
- Are  both of these っちろい the same (in both meaning and kanji) in both words
- Why not use 弱い instead? (Is it perhaps stylistic in choice, dialect based, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「弱{よわ}っ**ちろい**」

is the colloquial pronunciation of:

> 「弱っ**ちょろい**」

and I assure you that 「ちょろい」 is even listed in Jisho.

https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%82%8D%E3%81%84

All by itself, 「ちょろい」means "**easy**", "**slack**", "**superficial**" etc.  Note that there is ***no kanji*** for the word and it has nothing to do with 「白{しろ}い」. (I will come back to this point about 「白い」 at the end.)

With certain adjectives, however, 「ちょろい」 is attached like a suffix and when used this way, it just emphasizes the meaning of the preceding adjective in a very informal/colloquial way.

Those "compound adjectives" include: 「弱っちょろい」("**very weak**")、「甘{あま}っちょろい」{"**facile**", "**optimistic**", "**too green**" etc.}、「生{なま}っちょろい」("**half-hearted**"), etc.  Honestly, I could not think of another right now.  You cannot attach it to every adjective.

Lastly, there are two different 「生っちろい」.

1) colloquial form of 「生っちょろい」　meaning "half-hearted" as I stated above.

2) colloquial form of 「生白{なまじろ}い」 meaning "pale-looking".